# How to select all cell starting, containing or ending with some word with JQuery/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some cells in table like that and want to select it with JQuery?

For example:

```
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>John Doe1</td>
<td>1John Doe</td>
```

I want to select - starting from `1`, containing `Doe` and ending `1`.

How can I do with Jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can; have you made any attempts? Have you looked at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)? You have nearly 2000 reputation,  and a presence here for 4 years; you must know, by now, how the site works and what we expect of you?

Comment: Yeah for example in this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: And also there http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: You're asking for a jQuery solution, not a CSS solution (there isn't one, CSS selectors only apply to, and select, elements), which is why I linked you to the jQuery documentation instead.

Comment: I read also this https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Is it help you to answer?

Comment: i believe @DavidThomas is asking for you to put forth some effort and show us what you have tried, so that we, in good conscience, can help you solve your problem, not do it for you.

Comment: I don't need to know what you've read in order to answer the question; my point is that *you* need to make an attempt. If it doesn't work, fine, try again; if it still doesn't work and you don't understand why, then please: come back to us, ask us for help, show us your attempts. Show us that you've tried to solve your own problem with credible effort.

Comment: there are many many many examples of how to filter a table all over the web. At least try something

Comment: @DavidThomas I do not understand your behavior - you asked me two times because you do not want give any answer - when I show you that I spend a lot of time searching solution. Do you really not know rules of Stackoverflow - one of them is to ask question when I can not solve problem alone and spend some time??? Do you think that this site is for proofing that I spend 1h searching solution and found nothing - not for asking question if I spend 1h searching and finding nothing.

Comment: @DavidThomas How do you help me? Why do you not respond to any of my question? Quo vadis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expressions. These two regexp checks if text contain "John" (anywhere) and ends with "1":

```
$('#myTable').find('td').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    if (str.match("John") && str.match("1$") ) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red'); // ...or do something else with it.
    }
});
```

Comment: That is some idea to loop over elements I am not good in XPath and I am still thinking that I cant to something like this [name^="1"] or [name*="1"] or [name$="1"] like for attributes but for text but maybe it is not possible.

Comment: there's no CSS selector like that if that's what you mean. There was an idea, at some point, to include it in CSS3, but for some reason they ditched it. Using jQuery, you can check if any tag contains specific text like `$('td:contains("John")')` but not if it ends with certain char/string, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks for help I done iterative code with jQuery as you suggest I change match to search since faster and added 600ms delay before search - list is long so it is slower than delay. Today I am tryign to face nth-child() on visible elements. It looks that is not done yet in css.